# Cannot delete SQL datafile (.mdf) as its currently in use

Tags: sql-server

Cannot delete FOO.mdf from the data_files location as it says its currently in use. But the database using this mdf file has already been dropped. My guess is something corrupt went on during the dropping process.

How do I get this file deleted? I can't even copy the file to a different destination.

Comment: Are you sure `foo.mdf` was used by the database that you dropped? Have you checked the `sys.database_files` view for the remaining databases to see if any of them reference it?

Comment: `sys.master_files` will give you all database files for all databases in one go

Comment: What is your Operating System (OS)?